# jQuery shorthand if else by slider ui value define

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

By jQuery UI slide value define I would like to use if else shorthand statement but I'm not sure how to make this

I was trying the following but fails

```
values: [price !=='undefined' ? price[0], price[1] : <?= $sel_minmax['price_min'] ?>,<?= $sel_minmax['price_max']
```

the start point

```
   if(init_val.match(/price=[0-9]+;[0-9]+/)){
        var price = init_val.match(/price=[0-9]+;[0-9]+/);
        price = price[0].replace('price=','');
        price = price.split(';');
        price = price[0]+','+price[1];
        console.log(price);
    } else{
        price = <?= $sel_minmax['price_min'] ?> +','+ <?= $sel_minmax['price_max'] ?>;
    }
```

In this case the slider is getting stocked drag&drop stops to work, maybe the value what I pass can't be interpreted. `console.log(price)` shows the value as desired example `(123,345)`

than I have the slider value set it up as

```
values: [price],
```

Comment: Can you show your code with a traditional `if` statement?

Comment: If you're working that hard to translate your code, shorthand probably isn't a good idea anyway. Use a minifier instead.

Comment: I will paste here the traditional way what also fails

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: yes that won't get parsed by the browser. Netbeans shows unexpected ::

Comment: @fefe - so you need price to end up being an array with the two values? or do you need price to end up being a comma separated string of values?

Comment: let me make a an update on the last changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, what you are setting `price` to be is not able to be parsed because it's not a valid data type. You need `price` to either be an array of values `[123,345]` or a string `'123,345'`.

Because you're placing this in the slider and the slider expects an array, then you need to do this:

```
if(init_val.match(/price=[0-9]+;[0-9]+/)){
    var price = init_val.match(/price=[0-9]+;[0-9]+/);
    price = price[0].replace('price=','');
    price = price.split(';');
    price = [ price[0], price[1] ]; // creating an array of values
    console.log(price);
} else{
    price = [ <?= $sel_minmax['price_min'] ?>, <?= $sel_minmax['price_max'] ?> ];
}
```

Then pass `price` as the value to `values':

```
values: price, // price is already an array, so pass it as is
```

As far as using the ternary operator (although I don't recommend this as it's not readable at all):

```
values: (typeof price !=='undefined') ? [price[0], price[1]] : [<?= $sel_minmax['price_min'] ?>,<?= $sel_minmax['price_max']],
```

Comment: that's it works!! thank you!! just being newbie I don't have any glue if this is a good approach from my side what I was setting up